# REST api and caching

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, rest, caching, microservices

I have a resource called Sites.

I am planning to have an endpoint as follows:

/tenant/:tenantId/sites/:siteId

The endpoint is to return a site’s tree which will vary based on the userId extracted from the JWT token.

1. Since it will vary based on the user requesting it, should the endpoint have userId in the URI- may be as a query parameter?
2. How should caching work in this case?

The sites tree returned by this endpoint will also change based on updates in another resource (i.e users/groups)

Should the cache be discarded for all users whenever there is a change in the sites resource itself or when there is a change in groups?

I am using API gateway so will need to purge cache through client cache control header when any of the resources are updated.

Answer (score 2):

1. Since, the data will vary on the user requesting it, the endpoint should have the userId in the URI - it could be simply a path parameter similar to the `tenantId` and `siteId`
2. caching can be done on the basis of `If-modified-since` header to indicate if the data has changed or not.

The If-Modified-Since HTTP header indicates the time for which a browser first downloaded a resource from the server. This helps determine whether or not the resource has changed since the last time it was accessed.

Comment: how is  If-Modified-Since  to work with api gateway cache? @jain.saloni91

Answer (score 1):

1. From a security point of view if a user only can access his own sites the user id should not be on the path (or query param), because if you do that, any user can modify the URL in its browser and try to access the other user sites. To avoid that the URL should not have any userId (you can replace it with something like /me) and the service that will handle the request should extract the id information from the token
2. I don't know if you are using an in-memory cache of distributed cache and if sites/users/groups are different services (deployed on different servers) or if they live in the same application, anyway, when any of the resources that cache depends on are modified, you should invalidate the cache for that users

Comment: Thanks. I am looking for a reasonable way to discard that cache for users. We are using API gateway and lambda functions so there are no servers